# Two column text with rounded image on left column

Tags: html, css

[image: EXAMPLE]I am trying to achieve two column text with a rounded image on left column on the upper left corner.
So far I have done this:

```
<div class="photoside-left">
<img class="photo" src="http://verticaltaste.digitalemotion.ie/wp-
content/uploads/2017/09/photo.jpg" alt="Laura Cosoi">

<div class="drop-cap">
   <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but 
   the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, 
   or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are 
   going to use a passage of Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't 
   anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum 
   generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, 
   making this the first true generator on the Internet. It uses a 
   dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model 
   sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The 
   generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected 
   humour, or non-characteristic words etc. There are many variations of 
   passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered 
   alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which 
   don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of 
   Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden 
   in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet 
   tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true 
   generator on the Internet. It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, 
   combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem 
   Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore 
   always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic words 
   etc.</p>
</div>

</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 1100px) {
.photoside-left {
-webkit-box-flex: 1.5;
-webkit-flex: 1.5;
-ms-flex: 1.5;
flex: 1.5;
 }
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.photoide-left {
padding: 0 40px 0 0;
margin: 0 40px 0 0;
border-right: 1px solid #e7e4d3;
 }
 }
.photoside-left {
-webkit-flex-shrink: 1;
-ms-flex-negative: 1;
 flex-shrink: 1;
-webkit-box-flex: 1;
-webkit-flex: 1;
-ms-flex: 1;
 flex: 1;
 margin: 0 0 40px 0;
 }
@media (min-width: 1100px) {
.photo {
 width: 130px;
 height: 130px;
 }
 }
 .photo {
 border-radius: 50%;
 line-height: 0;
 border: 1px solid #e7e4d3;
 background-color: #fffef7;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 float: left;
 padding: 6px;
 margin: 0 20px 0 0;
 shape-outside: circle();
  }
.drop-cap p:first-child:first-letter {
 color: #333e48;
 margin: 4px 12px 0 0;
 border: 1px solid #e7e4d3;
 padding: 14px 15px 8px 15px;
 line-height: 32px;
 font-size: 52px;
 font-family: "Gilroylight";
 float: left;
 }
 @media (min-width: 800px) {
 .split-columns {
 -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
 -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
 column-count: 2;
-webkit-column-gap: 40px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-moz-column-gap: 40px; /* Firefox */
column-gap: 40px;
-webkit-column-rule: 1px solid #e7e4d3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
-moz-column-rule: 1px solid #e7e4d3; /* Firefox */
column-rule: 1px solid #e7e4d3;
}
```

The problem is if I add the class "split-columns" to the drop-cap div the image flow on the left hand side of the div which is something I dont want.

I would like to have the image in the corner in the same way as if it is a single column and the text to wrap around the image.

Thank you

Comment: can you make a quick [drawing](https://sketchboard.me) of what you want?

Comment: i have added the image with what I would like to achieve

Comment: Have a look at flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I have read that documentation many many times. Thanks anyway..

Answer (score 0):

I used a wrapper as a flexbox container so both sides will be next to each-other, and on-top of that, each of the two sides is by itself a flexbox container, so the text inside it will be centered both horizontally & vertically.

```css
html, body{ height:100% }
  
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height:50%;
}

.wrap img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

.wrap > div {
  flex: 1;
  border-left:1px solid black;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  
  /* center within each side */
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.wrap > div:first-child{ border:0; }
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <div>
    <img src='https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/5ae94a07635b11cb890559cb5febbd79?s=32'>
    text 1
  </div>
  <div>text 2</div>
</div>
```